# Use Kafka for warehousing without Zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to ingest data from a datawarehouse into kafka and then I want to store the avro records into mySQL RDMS. I want to eliminate the zookeeper dependency. Is it possible to do this without using zookeeper?

Comment: You cant start kafka without zookeeper.

Comment: Where can I find examples on how to do it?

Comment: @SrikanthKantamaneni Yes, you can. Lookup KRaft mode

Answer (score 1):

It is not considered production ready, but you are looking for Kafka KRaft mode.

`bin/test-kraft-server-start.sh` script will start the broker in this mode...

Docs - https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/raft

Reference - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-500%3A+Replace+ZooKeeper+with+a+Self-Managed+Metadata+Quorum