# Is KRaft (aka KIP-500) production mode available

Tags: apache-kafka

Can anyone confirm the KRaft (aka KIP-500) production mode available? I have checked the below links it says the  kraft is still an experimental feature and should not be used in production.

[Use Kafka for warehousing without Zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73386129/use-kafka-for-warehousing-without-zookeeper)

https://adityasridhar.com/posts/how-to-easily-install-kafka-without-zookeeper

Comment: There's some security features missing to properly be used in many production environments

Answer (score 0):

The wiki seems like the best place to get status on this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-833%3A+Mark+KRaft+as+Production+Ready

The kafka team seems to have planned to mark it ready in 3.3, which was supposed to be in August 2022, but it is now September and 3.2.3 was released on Sept 19.

So it sounds like it will be soon, but not just yet.

Comment: Maybe they'll announce at Kafka Summit next week

Comment: Looks like I was correct. https://kafka.apache.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

According to 3.3.1 release notes, it is production ready

https://kafka.apache.org/downloads